# NSLayoutFormatOptions has no member 'allZeros' error

Tags: ios

[image]I am trying to add several constraints programmatically inside the controller.

```
private func setupDownView(view: UIView) {
    let downView = try? DownView(frame: view.bounds, markdownString: "")
    downView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|",
        options: .allZeros,
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["view": downView!]))
    view.addSubview(downView!);
}
```

Auto-completion can complete this `allZeros` case for me. However, I have encountered an error of `no member allZeros`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[]` instead.

```
private func setupDownView(view: UIView) {
    let downView = try? DownView(frame: view.bounds, markdownString: "")
    downView!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(
        withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|",
        options: [],
        metrics: nil,
        views: ["view": downView!]))
    view.addSubview(downView!);
}
```